# Masking URL in Address Bar in IIS

Tags: rewrite, url, alias, iis-10, mask

I am not an expert in IIS and would really appreciate your help if this is something that can easily be resolved.

We have a web server on an intranet domain to which users are directed by the DNS when they go to https://application.intranet.com.  This mapping points users to the web server where the application is hosted. As soon as they arrive at the web server the address displayed in the URL address bar is changed to https://server.domain.com/PATH

Is there anyway in which one can mask the address that the users see to display https://application.intranet.com/PATH instead of the URL that are shown as soon as they receive a response from the web server?

We would simply want to mask the server's URL with the one that is used to direct the user to the web server.

Your help will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Typically, IIS leaves things alone, so it is likely that you have something in place that is changing from what the user enters to what you are seeing. Let's start with DNS. What are your DNS records (maybe `A` records, maybe `CNAME` records) for `application.intranet.com`? And for `server.domain.com`?

Comment: Thanks Doug, A record for application.intranet.com reads as follows: 
Server: DomainController.domain.com
Address: 10.46.1.16
Name: application.intranet.com
Address: 10.46.12.98

CName Record:
Server: *As above*
Address: *As above*

intranet.com
primary name server =  DomainController.domain.com
responsible mail addr = admin.domain.com
serial = 4965
refresh = 900 (15 mins)
retry = 600 (10 mins)
expire = 86400 (1 day)
default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

Comment: For server.domain.com info is as follows:

For server.domaim.com A Record:

Server: domaincontroller.domain.com
Address: 10.46.1.16

Name: server.domain.com
Address: 10.46.12.98

CName Record:

Server: DomainColntroller.domain.com
Address: 10.46.1.16

domain.com
primary name server = server.domain.com
responsible mail addr = it network
serial = 38681374
rest corresponds to CName record of application.intranet.com